# Loading Intel environment variables with shell script

Tags: fortran, sh, intel-fortran

I installed the Intel ifort compiler on my computer but before I can executed the command `ifort` I need to load the file:

```
. /opt/intel/composerxe/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

I don't want to load this in every session, therefor I don't want to put
it in my ~/.bashrc.

When I put this line in a Shell Script, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Load environment variables for Intel ifort + Intel MPI"
. /opt/intel/composerxe/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unknown switch ''. Accepted values: ia32, intel64
```

Is there another way to source the compilervars.sh with the intel64 flag?

Comment: Your script seems to have DOS line endings, in which case the actual argument to `compilervars.sh` is `intel64\r` (it includes the carriage return that is part of the `\r\n` pair that terminates the line).

Comment: @chepner: Oh I tried writing it again and it works on my working-station but the same script won't work on the server! I'm not sure what I can do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for details.

Comment: @chepner Thanks that did the trick. I had `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`!